# ReactJS Handling component changes

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS class that is rendering a form, and enabling/disabling the Submit button based on the inputs states. If all four fields are filled out, then the Submit button is enable, otherwise it's not.

It works fine when I have 4 basic inputs created with `React.DOM.Input`, however, I am struggling to make this work when adding a React component **DateTimePicker** from *react-widgets*.

The issue is that the Submit button will never be enabled since the `valid()` method is not called once the date is selected.

See code below:

```
DateTimePicker = require('react-widgets/lib/DateTimePicker');
momentLocalizer = require 'react-widgets/lib/localizers/moment'
momentLocalizer(require 'moment')

module.exports = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    date: ''
    project: ''
    description: ''
    duration: ''

  handleChange: (e) ->
      name = e.target.name
      console.log(name);
      console.log(e.target.value);
      @setState "#{ name }": e.target.value

  handleSubmit: (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
      $.post '/tasks', { task: @state }, (data) =>
        @props.handleNewTask data
        @setState @getInitialState()
      , 'JSON'

  render: ->

    dateChange = (date, dateStr) ->
      name = "date"
      @setState "#{ name }": dateStr

    React.DOM.form
      className: 'form-inline'
      onSubmit: @handleSubmit
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'form-group'
        React.createElement DateTimePicker,
          time: false
          name: 'date'
          value: new Date(@state.date)
          onChange: dateChange
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'form-group'
        React.DOM.input
          type: 'text'
          className: 'form-control'
          placeholder: 'Project'
          name: 'project'
          value: @state.project
          onChange: @handleChange
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'form-group'
        React.DOM.input
          type: 'text'
          className: 'form-control'
          placeholder: 'Description'
          name: 'description'
          value: @state.description
          onChange: @handleChange
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'form-group'
        React.DOM.input
          type: 'number'
          className: 'form-control'
          placeholder: 'Duration'
          name: 'duration'
          value: @state.duration
          onChange: @handleChange
      React.DOM.button
        type: 'submit'
        className: 'btn btn-primary'
        disabled: !@valid()
        'Add'

  valid: ->
      console.log @state
      @state.date && @state.project && @state.description && @state.duration
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `@setState` does not refer to the component `setState`. The `this` keyword (`@` in coffee) refers to the object the function belongs to, or the window object if it belongs to no object.

In your specific case, you should move the `dateChange` function out of the `render` method, and replace your onChange callback with `onChange: @dateChange`. That way, you will be updating the actual state of the component and not a member of the render method. Don't forget that in JavaScript, a function is an object.

```
[...]

dateChange: (date, dateStr) ->
    @setState "date": dateSt

render: ->
    React.DOM.form
      className: 'form-inline'
      onSubmit: @handleSubmit
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'form-group'
        React.createElement DateTimePicker,
          time: false
          name: 'date'
          value: new Date(@state.date)
          onChange: @dateChange
[...]
```